# Linux Mint losing/dropping/forgetting network connection spuriously

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

In what may be the most annoying wifi problem of my life, Linux Mint 17.1 64bit xfce can't seem to stay connected to its current wifi network.  The intervals are as narrow as 5 minutes, and as wide as an hour, between disconnects.  Whenever the connection is lost, the GUI still lists nearby wifi networks (from neighbors I'm assuming) but doesn't even show the one in the house.  Other devices remain connected to the in-house wifi without a problem.  The disconnects happen when someone is using the web browser, or when the computer is sitting inactive (but not suspending). As a result I can't reproduce the problem without just waiting for it to happen again.

I am able to get the wifi to come back up in a couple of ways, one is to use the GUI and uncheck then check "Enable Wi-Fi".  Alternatively, from the command line I can `sudo iwlist scan` or issue an active scan.  Both of these have the same effect, the wireless network is immediately found and reconnected to.

When disconnected, the following is output from `$ iwconfig wlan0`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

The description of the WiFi card from `lspci -v`

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8181
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at d0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-91-81-fe-ff-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
```

I didn't save the dmesg output from the last disconnect.  I will update the question when I see it again, but I remember it said something like `deauthenticated ... (reason=7)`